# I get an error "Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count"

Tags: vb.net, string

When im trying to put a previously defined variable as parameter of "MyString.Remove", Once I Debug it, I get an error which says "Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count"

The code is the following:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyString As String = "hello"
        Dim Chars As Integer = MyString.Length

        Dim Asdf As String = (MyString.Remove(1, Chars))
        TextBox1.Text = Asdf

    End Sub
End Class
```

By the way, what I want to do is to display the first and last letter of any word, in this case, "hello".

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The description for [String.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx) is:

> Deletes a specified number of characters from this instance beginning at a specified position.

You're saying remove from 1 to length, which will always be 1 above the last position. Either do:

```
MyString.Remove(1, Chars-1)
```

or even better:

```
MyString.remove(1)
```